# Compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that becomes compact again as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Reading the proof that the set of rational numbers is not compact as a subset of the real numbers I got the following question:

Is it possible to find a compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that becomes compact again as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? or this same theorem prevents us?

Comment: Every finite set is compact everywhere.

Comment: Are there **any** compact subsets of $\mathbb Q$ which aren’t compact in $\mathbb R?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A\subset\Bbb Q$, then $A$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb Q$ if and only if it is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$.

For instance, $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ is compact both as a subset of $\Bbb Q$ and as a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Actually, there is nothing specific about $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ here: a subset of a topological space $M$ is compact with respect to the subspace  topology if and only if it is compact as a subset of $M$.

Comment: This fact is often abbreviated as “ compactness is an intrinsic property “. It does not depend on the ambient space.